# How to capture text of parent element after checking text of child element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
store_block_list  = '//div[@class="amlocator-store-information"]'
anc ='//div[@class="amlocator-store-information"]/parent::div'


driver.get('https://www.charlottesweb.com/where-to-buy-charlottes-web/partner-locations')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
storeElement = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, store_block_list)))
full_list = []
address_list = []
for store in storeElement:
    address = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent;', store).strip()
    if address not in address_list:
        address_list.append(address)
        f=driver.find_element_by_xpath(anc)
        full_list.append(f.get_attribute('data-amid'))
driver.quit()
print(full_list)
```

I am going through this site and what I am trying capture text of address and append to address
_list if address not in the list and then move to data-amid and capture that, the reason I am not directly capturing the dat-amid is some of the address are not unique and I only want to capture the data-amid of unique address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture the data-amid you can run:

```
   parent = store.find_element_by_xpath('..')
   grandparent = parent.find_element_by_xpath('..')
   data_amid = grandparent.get_attribute('data-amid')
```

This will return the number value

One problem with your code is that you are searching for data-amid in 'f' which is using `find_element_by_xpath`, this will only return the first element found. Without moving up to the grandparent node the `get_attribute` call will only return 'None' and if you do move up from f to the grandparent `find_element_by_xpath` will always stop at the first element and return '1'.

If you move up the the grandparent node using `('..')` from 'store' twice and then run you can get the data-amid attribute.

Here it is in your code:

```
    driver.get('https://www.charlottesweb.com/where-to-buy-charlottes-web/partner-locations')
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    storeElement = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, store_block_list)))
    full_list = []
    address_list = []
    for store in storeElement:
        address = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent;', store).strip()
        if address not in address_list:
            address_list.append(address)
            parent = store.find_element_by_xpath('..')
            grandparent = parent.find_element_by_xpath('..')
            print(grandparent.get_attribute('data-amid'))
            full_list.append(grandparent.get_attribute('data-amid'))
    driver.quit()
    print(full_list)
```

Comment: I already got the address text, Actually what I am trying to do is once I append the address to the list then go upto the parent element and capture the data-amid
<div class="amlocator-store-desc" name="leftLocation" data-mapid="amlocator-map-canvas5e4c57eb11143" data-amid="1" xpath="1" style="">

Comment: I have edited my answer to show how to get the data-amid attribute.